# Build and deploy Dockerfile with ArgoCD

Tags: dockerfile, argocd

I am trying to load an application in ArgoCD, and for images stored in the registry all fine; but could it be possible to apply a Dockerfile to an image before deploying it, telling it to ArgoCD via helm chart/yaml app?

In the ArgoCD documentation, it seems to suggest that it's possible:
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/custom_tools/#byoi-build-your-own-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not possible. ArgoCD won't build images on its own, it's not its responsibility.

You have to build images and publish them somewhere to deploy them via ArgoCD. Like you would without ArgoCD: Kubernetes won't build images, it need to pull them from somewhere.

The link you are referring to is for building a custom ArgoCD image.